# My code does not work in different browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am creating a slideshow. It's pretty much working for me, but I have a problem. My content displays correctly in Firefox 12, but in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer 6 and 7 it does not display correctly. I tried to fix it for a long time, but no luck.

My expected output should be something like this:

[image: expected output]

This is my CSS:

```
.container{
  width:290px;
  //height:440px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  //padding-bottom:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slide1, .slide2, .slide3 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 440px;
    //border: 1px solid red;
}

.slide1 blockquote, 
.slide2 blockquote,  
.slide3 blockquote {
  margin:0;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  height: 250px;
  color:white;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s linear;
}

blockquote:after { 
  content: " "; 
  height: 0; 
  width: 0; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 100%; 
  border: solid transparent; 
  border-top-color: #DA532B;
  border-left-color:#DA532B;
  border-width: 10px; 
  left: 10%; 
} 

.slide1 blockquote { 
  background-color: #DB532B;
}

.slide2 blockquote { 
  background-color: purple;
}

.slide3 blockquote { 
  background-color: #54885F;
}


.leftquotes{
  position:absolute;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  font-size:5em;
  top:-18px;
  left:5px;
}

.rightquotes{
  position:absolute;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  font-size:5em;
  bottom:-10px;
  right:5px;
}

img{
  float:left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}


.slide1bottom {
    height: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    background: #DB532B;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slide2bottom {
    height: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    background: purple;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100px;
    bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slide3bottom {
    height: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    background: #54885F;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 200px;
    bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.image-name-container {
    height:110px;
     //margin: -15px 0 0 0;
}
.notactive {
    height: 10px;
    width: 90px;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
     margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

And this is all [code so far](http://jsfiddle.net/qNXHf/3/)

**EDIT:**

It seems, this css code not working with google chrome and IE 6,7

```
.slide1 blockquote, 
.slide2 blockquote,  
.slide3 blockquote {
  margin:0;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  height: 250px;
  color:white;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  position:relative;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: IE 6 7 and 8 don't support rgba colours, or even rgb, so that's your first problem. inline-blocks don't really work in IE6 or 7 either. Until IE10, CSS transitions aren't supported. IE6 and 7 also don't support :after. Those are your first things to look at :). I'd check it validates, then get it working in Chrome, then decide what matters in IE 8 and lower.

Comment: @RichBradshaw I tried it changing my code following your comment. But problem is same.

Comment: One silly question: Why do you wan't to add support for IE6? 
http://www.ie6countdown.com/ Less than 7% around the world use IE6. Unless your target is China.
and for IE7 http://www.rickwhittington.com/blog/should-my-website-support-internet-explorer-7/.
I would spare myself the headache and not support IE6 and IE7, and make a calculated risk of how many users of those about 6-7% that could be interested in visiting my website. That might be < 1%.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the height of the `.slide` elements to `440px`, when they only need to be `380px`, and you are using `bottom:2px` on the `.slide1bottom` etc. elements so they are moving all the way to the bottom of the container (440-2px).

Setting it to 380px solves the issue in chrome. I don't have time right now to look at IE.

```
.slide1, .slide2, .slide3 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 380px;
    //border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qNXHf/7/

Alternatively, if you want to maintain the original height, you could set the `.blockquote` elements to `height:310px` instead of `250px`.